# VS Winforms: Components (images, buttons, labels) are resizing and stretching on build

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

When I run my windows forms application (by clicking the start button in the top toolbar), the window's components like images, buttons and lables are stretched to a slightly different size and position. Is this fixed in later VS versions? What can I do to stop it?

[In Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZ13.png)

[In build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wfzu.png)

Comment: Do you have the latest VS2017 installed?

Comment: Your application is not DPIAware, you see the effect of virtualization (the *effect* includes the blurry aspect). [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) (and friends).

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, that worked!